# Hover Creation and image flip on a Custom shopify page I created

Tags: javascript, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant

How to create (add) Hover on  entire image and when you place mouse on image, image flips as in shows back picture of the product as well..I  made by buy button section below Navigation and want to add these features further. any tips?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XThHv.jpg)

Please Help